# Store large hierarchy in NoSQL each day and compare

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm in the process of creating a utility that stores a fairly large hierarchy into a NoSQL document. The data of this is similar to an Active Directory / LDAP structure which contains sub groupings, etc for each record.

These are fairly large, a JSON representation is about 40MB per copy.

Each day a new copy of this hierarchy would be added as a new document in the collection.

Through a web interface, a user would be able to select any two copies (documents) and they would be compared. The differences between the two would be displayed, sort of like a *diff* command would display differences between two documents.

My questions are

- Is NoSQL a good fit for storing a LDAP like structure for just viewing purposes?
- If so, what sort of techniques are useful for comparing two documents and getting the differences?

I'm currently trying this in MongoDB and I haven't figured out how to do a direct comparison from a MongoDB command to get the differences. So, my attempt so far is to simply export each record as a JSON text file and run a custom *diff* command to compare and format as needed.

I am curious if someone has a better method for this.

An example document in NoSQL

```
{
    date: "2013-06-10",
    users: [
        {
             _id: 1,
             dn: "CN=B A Baracus,OU=Testing,OU=People,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com",
             name: { first: 'B', middle: 'A', last: 'Baracus' },
             employeeId: ‘001234’,
             domain: 'mydomain',
             username: ‘babaracus’,
             created: new Date('Dec 03, 1924'),
             modified: new Date('Mar 17, 2007'),
             memberOf: [ 
                   "CN=TEST-DeleteMe,OU=Testing,OU=People,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com",
                   "CN=CTX - Epic Prod,OU=Access,OU=Groups,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com",
                   "CN=Public Folder Admins,CN=Users,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com",
                   "CN=Exchange Services,CN=Users,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com",
                   ...etc...
             ],
            ...etc...
        }
        ...etc...
    ]
}
```

Comment: JSON is just text like any other text is. So, it seems the method you chose isn't bad (especially if the json is formatted as nicely as showcased in your example).